# Why can't I resize the Toolshelf?

Tags: interface, customization

So my problem is that I cannot resize the toolshelf in any direction, which is really annoying since I don't see the tabs because there are so many of them. I'd like to resize it and I have no idea why I cannot. And it's just the toolshelf, other areas can be resized with no problem.
[image]

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more information. Some images could be very beneficial.

Comment: You can not resize the toolbar if what you are talking about is what I think it is. Try changing the DPI resolution in your User Preferences. Or use your MMB to click and drag to the left or right

Comment: Also, hover the mouse over the tabs and scroll with the wheel, to reach the hidden tabs

Comment: dpi doesn't help. I can't resize it with any of the mouse buttons. I can't change its width nor can I resize it vertically so that I could see the tabs better. I don't remember any major changes that could have caused this issue

Comment: I can't really understand what your issue is. What part of the toolbar are your trying to resize?

Comment: widening it, you know, normally it's LMB on the right border of the toolbar and dragging it changes its width, and you can also resize vertically right under where the tabs are. on the image, its above 'operator'. the cursor changes to left-right or up-down arrows that indicate when you can resize, only I cannot actually resize them

Comment: The image you edited in is not as helpful as it might be, because you did not include a screenshot of the full Blender window. There are tabs in the tool shelf which I don't recognize, suggesting that either you have some addons which have inserted elements into the tool shelf, or that you have done so yourself, so you might provide a list of any addons or other changes to the tool bar. Also, have you tried NUMPAD + to increase the size of the two parts of the tool shelf (they are stacked), and NUMPAD - (minus key on the numpad) to decrease the size of the two parts of the tool shelf?

Answer (score 1):

pressing **<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>** or **<kbd>Numpad -</kbd>** you can zoom in or out on any window (or control) in Blender.

To resize the panel drag it with the left mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Cegaton, comparing the image in your answer to the image in the original post (as edited), there is something else going on there, perhaps an addon that is throwing a wrench in the wringer. He does state in the answer that trying to move the tool shelf border using LMB doesn't work.

Comment: exactly brasshat. Thank you for understanding the problem. Now I've realised the plus sign which expands the properties panel doesn't work either, only the shortcut works. I'd like to solve it without reseting the interface settings.

Comment: try resetting to the factory settings. Then start adding your addons one by one until you find the one that is preventing you to work.

Comment: To expand on what cegaton said, you can choose File > Load Factory Settings without permanently altering your existing settings (as long as you don't save your preferences after loading). Then open your .blend and see if the problem has been resolved. The first step is to diagnose whether the behavior is caused by an add-on.

Comment: ok so I've loaded factory settings and enabled approximately all the addons I used before, and now it works, so it wasn't because of addons